# Why does Yahoo miss some mutual fund dividends/capital gains?

Tags: mutual-funds, dividends, yahoo-finance

I was looking at a mutual fund data on Yahoo Finance and I found some problems. 
I'll bring Fidelity's FBMPX as the first example to show what I found [[Link to Fidelity site]](https://fundresearch.fidelity.com/mutual-funds/fees-and-prices/316390681).

On Fidelity's site, it shows the following for Apr 6, 2011

- Capital Gain 0.25 per share
- Dividend 0.01 per share

I would assume that the total payout is then 0.26 per share
However, on Yahoo finance the dividend amount on the same date is 0.25.
It seems that Yahoo didnt include the dividend amount here and only shows capital gain

I'll use Fidelity's FSAGX as the second example [[Link to Fidelity site]](https://fundresearch.fidelity.com/mutual-funds/fees-and-prices/316390780)

On Fidelity's site, it shows the following for April 9, 2010

- Capital Gain 0.397 per share
- No dividend

Here I would assume the total payout to be 0.397 per share. However, on Yahoo finance the dividend amount on the same date is 0 (there isnt an entry for it). In this case then, Yahoo is ignoring the capital gain part.

Does anyone have any ideas about why Yahoo is ignoring certain payouts at times?

Comment: Yahoo is a website for all type for informations, so they can forgo detailed information. Fidelity on the other hand deals with financial information, and it pays for them to provide detailed information. Or it could there is a time lag between when Yahoo update's information on its website also.

Answer (score 2):

This looks more like an aggregation problem. The Dividends and Capital Gains are on quite a few occassions not on same day and hence the way Yahoo is aggregating could be an issue. There is a seperate page with Dividends and capital gains are shown seperately, however as these funds have not given payouts every year, it seems there is some bug in aggregating this info at yahoo's end.
For FBMPX
http://uk.finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=FBMPX&b=2&a=00&c=1987&e=17&d=01&f=2014&g=v

https://fundresearch.fidelity.com/mutual-funds/fees-and-prices/316390681

http://uk.finance.yahoo.com/q/pr?s=FBMPX